# Cannot escape exclamation mark in batch file

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I can't escape an exclamation mark using `^^!`. I know I need to either use `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` or just use `endlocal` but I can't find the right spot to put it without getting any errors.

Here is my script that is intended to display text at the horizontal center of the `cmd` window:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Center Text
mode 80,50

set "cmdwidth=80"
:Display
cls
set Center=This is a test^^! & call :CenterText Center strLen
echo.
pause
exit

:CenterText
  if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :CenterText
(endlocal & set %2=%len%)

goto CenterTextDisplay
:AddSpace
set "spaces=%spaces% "
goto :eof
:CenterTextDisplay
set /a "indent=(cmdwidth - strLen)/2" 
set "spaces= "
for /l %%a in (1,1,%indent%) do call :AddSpace
echo %spaces%%Center%
set "len=0"
goto :eof
```

This is my code without errors but I cannot escape the exclamation mark properly, the result is `This is a test` instead of `This is a test!`.

Comment: You don't need `delayedexpansion` - change the `!` to `%` in `:centertext` and lose the `endlocal`

Comment: @Magoo the batch file won't run when I change `!` to `%`, it just crashes

Comment: @Magoo, delayed expansion is in fact needed here due to nested expansion (`!%1!`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclamation marks get lost (or cause other unexpected results) every time delayed expansion is enabled, when a literal string contains exclamation marks, and also when a variable is expanded immediately (normal `%` expansion) that holds exclamation marks in its string value; the same is also true for `for` parameters (e. g., `%%I`) and argument references (e. g., `%1`), because all those are expanded before delayed expansion happens.
To avoid any such problems, delayed expansion should only be enabled when it is actually needed.

In your code, you enable delayed expansion globally. The variable `Center` actually holds the exclamation mark as you properly escape it, but it gets lost as soon as expanding `%Center%` in line `echo %spaces%%Center%`.

Here is the adapted script:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
title Center Text
mode 80,50

set "cmdwidth=80"
:Display
cls
set "Center=This is a test!" & call :CenterText Center strLen
echo/
pause
endlocal
exit /B

:CenterText
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:CenterText_Loop
if not "!%~1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :CenterText_Loop
endlocal & set "%~2=%len%"
set /a "indent=(cmdwidth-strLen)/2" 
set "spaces= "
for /l %%a in (1,1,%indent%) do call :AddSpace
echo(%spaces%%Center%
set "len=0"
goto :eof

:AddSpace
set "spaces=%spaces% "
goto :eof
```

Besides the correction of the delayed expansion issue, I also fixed the following things:

- changed `exit` to `exit /B` to only terminate the batch script but not the parent `cmd` instance;
- changed `echo.` to `echo/`, because the former might fail in case ther is a file called `echo` (no file name extension) in the current directory;
- improved `set` syntax by quoting the entire assignment expression consistently;
- changed `%1` to `%~1` and `%2` to `%~2` to remove potential surrounding quotation marks from the expanded values;
- moved subroutine `:AddSpace` downwards to clarify execution flow and to avoid need of label `:CenterTextDisplay` and the related `goto`;
  actually you could even remove that subroutine if you replace the command line `for /l %%a in (1,1,%indent%) do call :AddSpace` by this:

  ```
  for /l %%a in (1,1,%indent%) do call set "spaces=%%spaces%% "
  ```

  this illustrates an alternative to delayed expansion: doubling the `%` signs around a variable and using `call`; this does not work in all situations though, because some characters may still cause trouble and some commands (like `for` and `if`) cannot be run by `call`;